# This is our first /the first test this term

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, word-choice, difference

> This is our first test this term.
>
> This is our the first test this term.

Which one is right？Shouldn’t we put the in front of first? And why?

Comment: Why would you **ever** put a the there? Please do some research, on this site or online,  before posting questions like this. Possessive pronouns. Thanks.

Comment: This is our first test this term. This is the first test this term. But not both.

Comment: ***our*** and ***the*** are both *determiners*. Use one or the other (in this context, it makes no difference whatsoever). But you can't use *both*. And the default English sequence is *determiner [- adjective] - noun*.

Answer (score 0):

> *This is *our the* first test this term.

From Collins Dictionary,

> Most noun phrases contain only one determiner or none at all, but if there are more, they follow a definite order.

> There are two large groups [among four groups]:

> A ***the**, this, these, that, those, a(n), and the possessives my, your, her, his*, etc.

> B *another, some, any, no, either, neither, each, enough, a few, a little*.

I add ***our*** to group A.

> The words in groups A and B are known as the *central determiners*. A noun phrase will normally contain only one central determiner.

So it's clear that '*our the*' is not possible.  We use either one but not both.

['How do you use more than one determiner in noun phrases in English?'](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/how-do-you-use-more-than-one-determiner-in-noun-phrases-in-english) has more details on combination of determiners with two other groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to indicate possession, "the" is replaced by "our" in this sentence.

- This is **the** first test this term.
- This is **our** first test this term.
- This is **my** first test this term.
- This is **your** first test this term.
- This is **his** first test this term.
- This is **their** first test this term.